# SU Retag Request: [tools] <--> [utilities]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[tools](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tools) and [utilities](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utilities) are the same thing, right? I think they should be merged under [tools](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tools).

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made [utilities](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utilities) a synonym of [tools](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tools), as [tools](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tools) is more commonly used.

> updating post history, 254 rows affected 
>   updating posts, 187 rows affected 
>   updating PostTags associations, 171 rows affected 
>   removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected 
>   updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected 
>   merge of [tools] and [utilities] complete!