# Burninate the [tools] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Similar to [Kill the [software-tools] tag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4499/kill-the-software-tools-tag), I don't see the point in keeping [tools](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tools) around.

Typical meta tag. It doesn't explain what the question is about. If you're looking for a tool to do *something*, then tag it with *something*. Actually, if you're looking for "a tool", then probably your question suffers from the X Y Problem anyway.

Also, it raises the question where the difference is between a "tool", a "program", or software in general.

The tag doesn't make sense, therefore please burninate!

[image]

Comment: +1.  However, [this question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2257/su-retag-request-tools-utilities) from the related list shows that the opposite thing was done last year -- questions were retagged TO `tools`.

Comment: Well, that's not *really* the opposite, it's just that two meta-tags were merged into one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Why isn't that an SVG? :O